# DC motor in vacuum, heat generation

Tags: dc-motor, heat

I am designing a motor system that has to run in a vacuum chamber (sub mbar). I am a little bit worried about the heat that would not dissipate at all in the vacuum. Therefore, I want the least amount of energy wasted to heat(high efficiency). Some people advised me to get a big motor that is much more capable so that it can withstand the heat generated under low load.

The rpm I need ranges from 30 rpm to 600 rpm. So I need PWM on top of gearbox+motor. PWM and speed input will be controlled using Arduino. Also I realised that there are brushless and brushed motors. I figured that brushless motors are a bit more efficient which means less wasted as heat.

So in conclusion, I want a setup that is, big brushless motor + gearbox + PWM. Am I thinking correct? I have never gotten a chance to do any electrical engineering so I might be missing obvious flaws. Please let me know if there are any better ways to achieve this.

Additional info) I chose dc motor because the important part is to run continuously and smoothly at a set constant speed without bumps or jittering.
One session of running time would be ~10 minutes. Torque is not so much of a problem, probably maximum of 1000gcm needed I guess.

Comment: I would try and go with a big outrunner instead of a gearbox. Gearboxes are expensive. For low speed smoothness, you want a sensored drive. Maybe even a sensored sine drive so you can avoid the gearbox but 1kg-cm may not allow that.

Comment: You want a brushless motor because brushes and their lubricant will almost certainly contaminate your vacuum, and because if the vacuum is high enough the brushes will vacuum-weld to the commutator (unless you use graphite brushes, in which case the dust will *really* contaminate your vacuum).  Gearboxes have similar problems in a vacuum, so you should seriously consider direct drive.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you for your kind reply. Budget is less of a problem as the project is funded but I will definitely have a look into this outrunner thing. I am very new to any motors so need a little bit of time :)

Comment: I forgot to mention bearings -- you need bearings that are vacuum-rated, too, for the same reasons you need to worry about brushes and gears.

Comment: @TimWescott Thank you Tim. Ah I didn't really think through that it can happen with the gearbox. I will have to do without it then. I learned much just from your a few lines of comment. Thank you

Comment: Don't be surprised if you end up rolling your own.

Comment: @TimWescott I am so afraid that you might be right. :/ Hopefully not

Comment: outrunners are inside out brushless motors and have many poles as a result of being inside out so can run very slowly. Model airplanes use them so they aren't too costly. The sensored sine wave drive is the pricey difficult to find thing. The bearings are also easy to replace so you can shove in vacuum rated ones. Stay away from gearboxes if you don't need compactness or low weight. Too custom and expensive.

Comment: An outrunner is probably *not* what you want, as there's no ready way to get the heat out of the coils.  Consider something like a stepper (probably with low steps/revolution) or else a conventional inrunner, and then wrap malleable tubing around the outside and pipe a coolant through that.  If you are going to use an inrunner, at least machine a custom center/mount from aluminum and heatsink it to something like an aluminum base of the chamber, with the goal being to maintain a large cross section.  This question isn't really on topic, you do not yet even know if you really have a problem.

Comment: An oversized motor will give you more mass to store the heat, but it will be less efficient. The most efficient motor would be one that is closely sized to the requirement. Add mass by mounting it to a block of metal. If possible, mount it to a good heat conductor that serves as part of the vacuum chamber wall.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thank you so much for the opinion on the oversized motor. I was really curious about that. So I was mostly wrong on my idea and I am so glad to find it out here! Thank you, everyone, what a joy to be here learning more from experts.

Comment: Most of the heat in an in-runner BLDC motor will be generated in the stator windings, conducted to the stator laminations, and from there to the housing. Added metal should contact as much of the housing as possible.

Comment: How much mechanical power will you need ? 600rpm and 1000g.cm is about 6W. Can you transmit the mechanical force through the vacuum chamber enclosure using magnetic coupling?

Comment: @peufeu The torque I estimated was very crude because the motor has to work against unknown friction. So I only have an actual idea on rpm but not the power. Unfortunately it will not be possible to deliever force from the outside, the whole system except the controller will have to stay inside the chamber. I will post a new question soon. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

Your worst case is that you have a perfect vacuum and no heat path out of your chamber.  600 rpm at 1000 gcm is about 6 watts of mechanical power.  I wouldn't choose a big motor because it would be less efficient; rather, choose a "right-sized" brushless motor and gearbox for your speed and load.  You should be able to achieve at least 50% efficiency, meaning that 6 watts will be going into your load and 6 watts will be lost as heat.  If you run for 10 minutes (or 600 seconds), 6 watts will produce 3600 joules or 860 calories.  You only need to attach a heat sink capable of absorbing 860 calories.  Aluminum has a specific heat of 0.215 calories/gram-Kelvin.  Do the math, and 200 grams of aluminum heat sink will have a temperature rise of 20 degrees K.  So attach a heat sink and you can play around with the time, losses, and thermal mass until you get what you need.  Of course, you must cool it after each run by allowing air in for convection or some other heat path out of your chamber.  Otherwise the temperature will continue to rise with each run.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh... I could not have asked for more! Fantastic guideline and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend putting the motor outside of the vacuum and use a magnet-coupled drive through the container wall.

Another option is using an AC induction motor and putting the coil outside of the vaccum for better heat transfer. This is done for high-power X-ray tubes to rotate the anode. Again, the reason is better heat transfer.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_anode_x-ray_tube_(labeled).jpg]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_anode_x-ray_tube_(labeled).jpg

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the chamber is fairly big and it would be hard to make a way to deliver the force from outside.